# Node module Knex.js and browserify issue

Tags: node.js, browserify, knex.js

I have a node module named product which uses knex.js and sqlite3, it runs fine on node. Now I am trying to use browserify to run it on browser by including the bundle js file generated by browserify in html as below

```
<script src="product.bundle.js"></script>
```

below are the node and npm versions:

```
Node: 12.18.0
npm: 6.13.7
```

Package.json:

```
{
  "name": "product",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "knexjs sample module",
  "main": "product.js",
  "dependencies": {
    "knex": "^0.21.1",
    "sqlite3": "^4.2.0",
    "browserify": "^16.5.1"
  }
}
```

product.js

```
const sqlite = require( 'sqlite3' )

const knex = require('knex')({
    client: 'sqlite3',
    connection: {
        filename: "./mysqlitedb.sqlite"
      }
});

module.exports = {
    init: function(){
        knex.schema.createTable('products', (table) => {
            table.increments('id')
            table.string('code')
            table.string('description')
            table.string('price')
        }).then(() => console.log("table created"))
            .catch((err) => { console.log(err); throw err })
            .finally(() => {
                knex.destroy();
            });
    },
    insertIntoProductsTable: function(){
        const products = [
            { code: 'Product code 1', description:'Product desc 1', price: '11.00' }
        ]
        
        knex('products').insert(products).then(() => console.log("data inserted"))
            .catch((err) => { console.log(err); throw err })
            .finally(() => {
                knex.destroy();
            });
    },
    getAllProducts: function(){
        knex.raw( 'select * from products' )
        .then( function( products ){
            console.log( products )
        })
        .catch( function( err ){
            console.log( err )
        })
        .finally(() => {
            knex.destroy();
        });
    }
}
```

Using the command " browserify product.js -o product.bundle.js " got the product.bundle.js file.
When try to load that on browser getting following error:

[image]

[image]

please let me know, if I am missing anything or is there any links where I can check if anything similar is implemented?

thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Your error is telling you that the `stream` module (usually present in the node environment) is not present in the browser environment. This is true of a number of node prerequisites (like `fs`). SQLite3 also has a native compiled code component to it which definitely won't run in the browser. You're better off either storing data on a server, or using a different technology for local storage.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I was trying this based on what is mentioned on knex.js page I.e, "Knex can be built using a JavaScript build tool such as browserify or webpack. In fact, this documentation uses a webpack build which includes knex. View source on this page to see the browser build in-action (the global knex variable).". Do I have to use some thing else along with browserify or webpack?

Comment: Knex can, but SQLite cannot. The most you could do with Knex in the browser is generate the SQL queries (which is what the Knex documentation is using it for, I believe) but not execute them. There may be a way to execute queries against sql.js, you'd have to do some research there.

Comment: thanks, will check out sql.js. sorry, I still have this question that even without knex.js, if I build a node module with any of the DB drivers like sqlite3, postgres etc... and use webpack/ browserify to bundle it as a JS file. can I use that on my browser? or we can not use browserify/webpack in such cases?

Comment: Yes, many node modules will build for the browser very nicely. There are a few cases where they won't: when they contain native code (like SQLite) or when they depend on access to system resources like the filesystem that the browser by design prevents us from accessing.